# How to delete from Mysql Database an item selected in a Listbox Python Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

i have made a database with 3 columns(id, name, price) and since i can't display all the columns in the Listbox i am displaying only the column "name", so i want to be able to delete an item in the database based on the name of the product i am clicking on the Listbox.
here is the code, i hope it helps:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
root = Tk()

root.geometry('700x500')

con = mysql.connector.connect(user = '', password = '', host = '127.0.0.1', database = 'anime')

concursor = con.cursor()

concursor.execute('select * from prod')
query = concursor.fetchall()

l = Listbox(root)

for x,y,z in query:
    l.insert(x+1, y)


l.pack(anchor='w')

#function to delete prod

def delp():

    sel_items = l.curselection()
    for item in sel_items:
        concursor.execute("delete from prod where name = ('{}')".format(item))
    con.commit()

button1 = Button(root, text = 'prod del', command = delp)
button1.pack(anchor='w')

root.mainloop()
```

and this is the database picture:
[image]

the python code works only if i replace "name" with "id" in the query in the "delp" function, however when i select the 1st item in the listbox, it deletes the 2nd item int the database, and i want to be able to delete based on the name.

Comment: You should insert the `name` (`y` in for loop) column instead of `id` (`x`) column from db into listbox.  And `l.curselection()` returns the selected indexes, not the contents.

Comment: @acw1668 when i just insert the "name"(y in for loop) instead of x+1, y or x, y i get the error "bad listbox index (name of the item) must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number", is there a way  to get the contents from the listbox so i can delete from the db based on the name? if you know something other than the listbox that could do the work it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it out, so heres the answer for ones whom are/will be looking for this.

first we wont need the curselection()
we need to get the active item or Anchor and "string it" and then use it in the query with format.
heres the code to make sense

```
    def delp():
        sel_items = l.get(ACTIVE)
        string_item = str(sel_items)
        for item in sel_items:
            concursor.execute("delete from prod where name = ('{}')".format(string_item))
        con.commit()
```

this code will delete the items in the database based on the name select in the listbox.